# Passing data from Component A to Component B using service - Angular 2

Tags: angular2-services, subject

Hi I am trying to pass a object from Component A to another sibling Component B and I am using service to do so and I am using Subject. But when calling the get method from service I am not able to get the data in Component B. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be great. My code is as below -

**Hierarchy Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HierarchyService {

  private dataObj = new Subject;
  getDataObj = this.dataObj.asObservable();

  constructor () {}

  setData(setData:Object){
    console.log("setData +++ ", setData);
    this.dataObj.next(setData);
  }
}
```

**Component A**
Inside a event handler I am setting below code -

```
this.hierarchyService.setData(treeModel);
```

**Component B**
inside ngOnInit I am trying to get the data that I set in Component A

```
 this.hierarchyService.getDataObj.subscribe(data => console.log("data ", data));
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, I was actually injecting the hierarchy service as provider for Component A and Component B. Instead I just added the service as provider for my app.module and removed as providers from Component A and Component B and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

How are you using your services is not very clear.

Are you using providers: [] on both component? in that case the both uses different instantiation and are not singleton, so data cannot be shared.

Put your service in providers array in `app.module` and try again.

If you want to use the  @Input() @Output() to share the data then see this post [Angular component communication by using Input Output decorator](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1219/angular-component-communication-by-using-input-output-decorator)

Comment: Thanks Ali, Yes initially I was adding my service in providers for both the component that's why I was not able to get data as each component was creating singleton instance. Then I removed it and just added it to the    app.module and it worked fine.